# Centering labels on the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got a problem with labels on chart. Text label is centered badly or it is missing.

For example: 
jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/

Screenshot: (Firefox browser)
[image]
And it works well only in chrome.

I'm using version 4.1.0. (Created: 16.02.2015)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to set [allowOverlap](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap) to false.

Comment: Nothing :( Default **allowOverlap** is setting on false. Please note that labels are not centered. Numbers 31,  4054 etc. It works well in chrome.

Comment: My bad, I mean set it to true.. http://jsfiddle.net/p3dkefgx/ ;)

Comment: Result in my browsers: http://wgrajo.pl/img/screenshoo.png . Labels as not centered :(

Comment: Ah right, issue in Chrome, I misread as issue in Chrome, sorry :) Yesterday wasn't my best day, bug reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3842) - Thanks!